# Command to get only the load average Linux

Tags: linux, load, uptime

I need a command to get a output of the load average of linux system to use on a script.

I know the command `uptime`, but using that command I get all that stuff i don't want, like: `12:09:31 up 20:57,  2 users,  load average: 0.12, 0.10, 0.09`.

How can I get only the load average on the output?

Like this: `load average: 0.11` (for example)

Thank you for your help and sorry my poor english.

Comment: Have you checked the `/proc` filesystem? Maybe you should?

Comment: ty @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: uptime | awk '{print $8}'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just googled and found this.

Hope this helps :

http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-08-08/linux-load-averages.html

I think this command will solves your question.

`cat /proc/loadavg`

Comment: Yeah, I know that command but it shows the load with other values, ty anyway.

Comment: Have you seen the next command : **cat /proc/loadavg**. And btw it would be helpful if you express what type of result you expected.

Comment: I have edited my answer check it out!

Comment: If you are only interested in the load averages then you can do something like this as well: 

```uptime | cut -d ',' -f 4-6 | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'```