# Variables fetched from hosts get sorted as strings, not floats, and printed out without host name info

Tags: ansible

Here's a playbook used for fetching average load of each host:

```yaml
---
-
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Check node load
      ansible.builtin.command: uptime
      register: node_load

    - name: Extract load averages
      set_fact:
        load_averages: "{{ node_load.stdout | regex_search('\\d+\\.\\d+, \\d+\\.\\d+, \\d+\\.\\d+') }}"

    - name: Convert average load to float
      set_fact:
        average_load_5m: "{{ load_averages.split(',')[1].strip() | float }}"

    - name: Format load averages
      set_fact:
        formatted_load: "Avg. Load: {{ load_averages.split(',')[0].strip() }} [1m], {{ load_averages.split(',')[1].strip() }} [5m], {{ load_averages.split(',')[2].strip() }} [15m]"

    - name: Print formatted average load of each host
      debug:
        msg: "{{ formatted_load }}"
      notify: Sort hosts by 5m load average

  handlers:
    - name: Sort hosts by 5m load average
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map ('extract', hostvars, 'average_load_5m') | list | sort }}"
...
```

It works correctly up to the point where I want to have the hosts sorted by average 5-min. load: the handler seems to be never reached although the playbook finishes successfully.

What may be the reason I don't get the last section (sorting and displaying results) processed?

---

UPDATE:

After moving the handler to the task section, I managed to get some output printed out:

```yaml
---
-
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    user_dir: /var/fpwork/wojtyna
  tasks:
    - name: Check node load
      ansible.builtin.command: uptime
      register: node_load

    - name: Extract load averages
      set_fact:
        load_averages: "{{ node_load.stdout | regex_search('\\d+\\.\\d+, \\d+\\.\\d+, \\d+\\.\\d+') }}"

    - name: Convert average load to float
      set_fact:
        average_load_5m: "{{ load_averages.split(',')[1].strip() | float }}"

    - name: Format load averages
      set_fact:
        formatted_load: "Avg. Load: {{ load_averages.split(',')[0].strip() }} [1m], {{ load_averages.split(',')[1].strip() }} [5m], {{ load_averages.split(',')[2].strip() }} [15m]"

    - name: Print formatted average load of each host
      debug:
        msg: "{{ formatted_load }}"

    - name: Sort hosts by 5m load average
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map ('extract', hostvars, 'average_load_5m') | list | sort }}"
...
```

However, the printout is somewhat confusing:

```
TASK [Sort hosts by 5m load average] ************
ok: [host2.example.net] => {
    "msg": [
        "0.07",
        "0.07",
        "0.62",
        "1.13",
        "1.18",
        "1.4",
        "138.0",
        "18.73",
        "2.47",
        "2.63",
        "22.38",
        "35.21",
        "4.03",
        "48.71",
        "5.47",
        "65.72",
        "9.65"
    ]
}
### repeated for each host
```

As you can see, the values are sorted... as strings. The other problem is, there's no information on which host the values belong to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just and only gather the remote fact. There is absolute no need for `command` or `shell`, `set_fact` and `regex_search` at all.

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Find out what the Remote Machine's loadavg is
    slurp:
      src: /proc/loadavg
    register: loadavg

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ (loadavg.content | b64decode).split(' ') | first }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Find out what the Remote Machine's loadavg is] ******
ok: [one.example.com]
ok: [two.example.com]

TASK [debug] **********************************************
ok: [one.example.com] =>
  msg: '1.06'
ok: [two.example.com] =>
  msg: '0.00'
```

If one like to have the `inventory_hostname` in front of the value instead of only the TASK headline one may use

```yaml
"{{ inventory_hostname }}: {{ (loadavg.content | b64decode).split(' ') | first }}"
```

**Documentation**

- [Command to get only the load average in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48521302/6771046)
- [`slurp` module – Slurps a file from Remote Nodes - Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html#examples)
- [Splitting string by whitespace and then joining it again in Ansible/Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39794185/6771046)

---

Regarding

> ***As you can see, the values are sorted... as strings.***

use `version_sort` instead. See in example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77537901/6771046).

---

Regarding the task

> ***`- name: Convert average load to float`***

such is not possible.

A minimal example task

```yaml
- name: Convert to float
  set_fact:
    loadavg: "{{ 1.23 | float }}"

- name: Show value and type
  debug:
    var: loadavg ~ ' ' ~ loadavg | type_debug
```

will always result into

```yaml
TASK [Show value and type] *************************
ok: [one.example.com] =>
  loadavg ~ ' ' ~ loadavg | type_debug: 1.23 unicode
```

See **Documentation**

- [`set_fact` module – Set host variable(s) and fact(s) - Notes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html#notes)

  > *Some boolean values (`yes`, `no`, `true`, `false`) will always be converted to boolean type, unless `DEFAULT_JINJA2_NATIVE` is enabled. This is done so the `var=value` booleans, **otherwise it would only be able to create strings**, but it also prevents using those values to create YAML strings. Using the setting will restrict k=v to strings, but will allow you to specify string or boolean in YAML.*